# Maintaining an active FB auth session for a website

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I've found several questions that are sort of similar to mine, but not 100%.

I've got a site which has normal user accounts. You have the option of using FB auth as well. The problem is often when the user visits the page (sometimes even after a few hours) even though the users account cookie is still valid, their facebook session is not.

So the user appears to be logged in, (the webpage says "Hi, [user]") but I have no facebook session, and any facebook API call will fail until they re-click "login with facebook". -- This is all despite the fact that I'm still logged in to facebook.

Now, I did a similar implementation about 11-9 months ago, and the facebook session rarely ever expired. Now it seems to happen every few hours. Oddly, other websites which use facebook auth don't seem to be suffering from this problem.

Any idea what I can do to keep the facebook session alive for as long as possible?
Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people combine the php-sdk with the js-sdk. This looks for auth events and will usually trigger a reload of the page signing the user back in to facebook

There's some sample code on the developer site, just **above** the following anchor

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#insights

Comment: Originally I had this set up, however I found that the JS SDK would *not* refresh the page. It would only do so when you click the 'facebook login' button, but not if you just viewed the page. So, it wasn't helping at all.

Comment: Also, I hear FBML is being depricated?

Comment: You can replace the login button with <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl();?>">Connect</a>. I've used that code a lot and it works for me, and I had a similar situation to yourself. There are some posts that suggest putting the window.location.reload call into a window.setTimeout

Comment: Ah, now it's starting to come back to me. One problem that was really troubling with the JS SDK, was that if I used 'status : true' as a param to the window.fbAsyncInit function. It would, indeed, refresh the page with my facebook token. *however* Then, I wouldn't be able to actually log out of the page. Everytime I did, it would load the main page, try to get a token (and get one) and then log me back in right away. I tried some hacking about, to dynamically set the status param, but in the end it was causing more problems than it was worth... :/